# how can I set user-level in MenuItem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I need to set a value in default whatever value come mean based on the previous selection in Userlevel dropdown value will come so what my task is I need to set that value in default selected because at I time one value come true so if user select any one name in the previous drop down so for example in Username drop-down dev_sams select so I need to set maker to direct in Userlevel default value label will change according to Username so need to set dynamic I added some example how value and label come for better understanding see CodeSand Box link

```
import React, { useMemo } from "react";
import {
  Grid,
  Card,
  CardContent,
  Button,
  Box,
  TextField,
  MenuItem,
  makeStyles
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  formGrid: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  tableContainer: {
    maxHeight: 440
  }
}));
const userList = [
  {
    username: "aabcd@email.com",
    maker: true,
    checker1: false,
    checker2: false,
    checker3: false,
    checker4: false,
    checker5: false
  },
  {
    username: "aabc@email.com",
    maker: true,
    checker1: false,
    checker2: false,
    checker3: false,
    checker4: false,
    checker5: false
  },
  {
    username: "aabcssd@email.com",
    maker: false,
    checker1: true,
    checker2: false,
    checker3: false,
    checker4: false,
    checker5: false
  },
  {
    username: "dev_sams",
    maker: true,
    checker1: false,
    checker2: false,
    checker3: false,
    checker4: false,
    checker5: false
  },

];
export default function Downloads() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const downloadsForm = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      Username: "",
      Userlevel: ""
    },
    // validationSchema: downloadFormSchema,
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    }
  });
  const options = useMemo(() => {
    if (userList) {
      let levelList = [];
      for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(userList)) {
        if (value === true) {
          levelList.push({ value: key, label: key });
        }
      }
      return levelList;
    }
  }, [userList]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (userList) {
      downloadsForm.setFieldValue("baseStr", options[0]);
    }
  }, [options, userList]);
  return (
    <Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Card color="primary" variant="outlined">
          <form onSubmit={downloadsForm.handleSubmit}>
            <CardContent>
              <Grid xs={12} item container>
                <Grid item xs={6} className={classes.formGrid}>
                  <TextField
                    id="outlined-select-currency"
                    select
                    label="User"
                    fullWidth
                    onChange={downloadsForm.handleChange}
                    value={downloadsForm.values.Username}
                    name="Username"
                    error={downloadsForm.errors.Username}
                    helperText={downloadsForm.errors.Username}
                    variant="outlined"
                    size="small"
                  >
                    {userList?.map((opt) => (
                      <MenuItem key={opt.username} value={opt.username}>
                        {opt.username}
                      </MenuItem>
                    ))}
                  </TextField>
                </Grid>
                {downloadsForm.values.Username && (
                  <Grid item xs={6} className={classes.formGrid}>
                    <TextField
                      id="outlined-select-currency"
                      select
                      label="Level"
                      fullWidth
                      onChange={downloadsForm.handleChange}
                      value={downloadsForm.values.Userlevel}
                      name="Userlevel"
                      variant="outlined"
                      size="small"
                    >
                      <MenuItem value={options}>{options}</MenuItem>
                    </TextField>
                  </Grid>
                )}
              </Grid>
              <Grid xs={12} item className={classes.formGrid}>
                <Box
                  display="flex"
                  alignItems="flex-end"
                  flexDirection="column"
                >
                  <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit">
                    Submit
                  </Button>
                </Box>
              </Grid>
            </CardContent>
          </form>
        </Card>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-glitter-vb2ks?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: The expected behaviour is not clear from your explanation . What should happen to the Level Textfield when i select a value in the User dropdown ? Should it be auto populated with "true" or "false" ???

Comment: you can see I updated code with some data on how data is coming

Comment: so true and false with its value so depend on user dropdown selected we will select true for level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we select a username we need to the below things,

1. get the options for the user level for the selected user
2. prepopulate the user level with the first option

we need to have a custom method that should do the above steps for us when ever the selected value changes. create a new method called `handleUserNameChange` as below

```
const handleUserNameChange = (e) => {
    const selectedUser = e.target.value;

    // find the user
    const user = userList.find((user) => user.username === selectedUser);

    // iterate over the user object and generate the option list
    // containing the property which has the value true
    const newOptions = Object.keys(user).reduce((optionList, key) => {
      if (user[key] === true) {
        optionList.push({ value: key, label: key });
      }
      return optionList;
    }, []);

    // have a state to hold the options which changes based on the selected user
    setOptions(newOptions);

    // Manually update the formik state for username
    downloadsForm.setFieldValue("Username", selectedUser);

    // Manually update the formik state for userlevel by setting the
    // first option as default
    downloadsForm.setFieldValue("Userlevel", newOptions[0]?.value || "");
  };
```

Now use this method in the onChange of your `Username` textfield.

```
onChange={handleUserNameChange}
```

Since the options changes everytime based on the selected user we can have one state to hold these options .

**Working Sandbox**

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-snowflake-gng1m?file=/src/App.js)